# how to create a job to split the MDF file into many ndf files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a developer and somehow managed myself to get involved in this.
There are many databases, and there is only one mdf for each of the databases and no ndf till now.

Now that these databases are growing ,I have to create a job which will find out which MDf file is approaching or already exceeded the size of 100 gig and 
then I have to split the MDF into more ndf files to share the load and improve the performance.

I was suggested to create the new ndf files in the same primary file group whenever required(mdf is exceeded the limit) and then shrink the mdf to forcefully to move the data to the new ndf. then rebuild the indexes and the task is done.

After  a bit of research I am pretty convinced that I can do it a better way by adding the new files into new file groups and moving the indexes from the large table to the new ndf file.
The no. of large tables in the database is very few and around 80% of data resides in those tables.

now the problem is, there are many databases and it has to be done via a job running in the background.and it should work for all the databases.

Can you please suggest, how should I achieve this ? 
Meaning once the split is done for the first time and new filegroup and ndf is created 
and the indexes moved to ndf file.What should be done when next time mdf is approaching the limit ?

or is there any downside of this approach and I should stick to creating a new ndf in the same filegroup and empty the mdf whenever reaching the limit ?

and it will be great if someone can suggest me how to do it dynamically?
Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/08/02/moving-data-from-the-mdf-file-to-the-ndf-file-s.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Microsoft%2FSqlServerTipsTricks%20%28Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Tips%20%26%20Tricks%29) gives some nice detailed info on how to get your desired results. You can expand that with the [sp_MSforeachdb](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/) command to execute your script on each database. This does however become very very risky at this point.

One thing you might want to consider is to look into the expected growth and other increases and plan something to accomodate that for the next 6 to 12 months and just do it manually once or twice a year. If that is not possible, there is a middle ground where you script the moving of data for the large tables only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! .. and does it make sense that I create a new filegroup for the non clustered index of large tables as a one time activity(may be some maintenance required later) and create a script to add another ndf file in the primary filegroup to empty the data from mdf when it reaches to the limit ?

Comment: one question I have on this, why the new filegroup? what specifically do you want to achieve with that? If you consider to put the actual file on a different physical drive it would be needed, otherwise I dont see the added value that outweighs the added complexity. It might seem like a small thing but consider you recovery plan bewfore and after these changes and you will see what i mean ;)  Also, if the answer is complete and to your liking, mark is as answered :D

Comment: I am trying to get a performance improvement by storing indexes separately in different file groups(may be on different disks) ... also I have a concern that if I'll keep creating the ndf files in the same group, the primary group will be full soon...